# How to catch an AccessViolationException in C# from a C++ dll which is wrapped in a C# dll using SWIG

Tags: c#, c++, exception, swig

I am using a function from an auto generated C# dll in my C# code. The auto generated C# dll is a wrapper for a C++ dll, I think the code is mostly auto generated with SWIG, but I don't know more about it. I think it basically just wraps the C++ functions using PINVOKE (but I am not sure how the SWIG stuff works). 
The problem is that I can not catch an exception, when it occurs in the C++ dll. In my Case the `frame()` method throws an `AccessViolationException`, but I can not catch it with a try catch block. Does SWIG provides some sort of exception handling for C#? I just want to prevent my application crash.

The function from the wrapper dll (C#):

```
public virtual void frame() {
    osgViewerPINVOKE.ViewerBase_frame(swigCPtr);
  }
```

The C++ Code:

```
 SWIGEXPORT void SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_ViewerBase_frame(void * jarg1) {
 osgViewer::ViewerBase *arg1 = (osgViewer::ViewerBase *) 0 ;

      arg1 = (osgViewer::ViewerBase *)jarg1; 
      (arg1)->frame();
    }
```

My C# code, where I want to catch exceptions:

```
try
{
    this.viewer.frame();
}
catch (AccessViolationException exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
}
```

I have read this article from SWIG: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html#csharp_exceptions
But I do not understand much of it. Do I need to edit the C++ dll? Because this is no option for me. I could only modify the wrapper class, but I would prefer not to do so.

Comment: Are you able to catch it with 
"catch (Exception exception)"
?

Comment: No, of course I tested that first.

Comment: (arg1)->frame(); <------------- what is this frame function? What is the namespace of ViewerBase in the C++ code? do you have access to the code? My guess is its a built in function. What may be happening is that function launches whatever it does on a separate thread which is a different stack. You can't catch the exception in your catch block if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @CarCar, but I think I have found a solution for my problem. It  is not actually fixing the problem I am describing here, but I have found the reason why the "frame()" function crashes and I am preventing the error.
I could explain you what frame does, but there is no need to do so anymore. In short: It is part of some 3D rendering for a 3D viewer based on Open Scene Graph, the Problem was that frame() functions requires at least OpenGL version 4.2, so I am simply checking the version, before I run it.